# Spivak problem on Schwarz inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have a question regarding problem 19 in the 3rd Ed. of Spivak's Calculus. Specifically, part (a). The question concerns the Schwarz inequality:
$$
x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 \leq \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2} \ .
$$
It says to prove that if $x_1=\lambda y_1$ and $x_2 = \lambda y_2$ for some number $\lambda$, then equality holds in the Schwarz inequality.

Substituting the given values for $x_1$ and $x_2$ we have
$$
\lambda (y_1^2+ y_2^2) \leq |\lambda|(y_1^2+y_2^2) \ .
$$
It appears to me that equality can only hold if $\lambda \geq 0$. Can someone explain to me how equality holds for any given $\lambda$?

Comment: It depends on which version you use. Some assume that all the variables are non-negative. Other versions use the absolute value. Considering that you have $|\lambda|$, you should also have $|x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_2|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a typo. You need $\lambda\ge 0$.

Comment: Was this supposed to be an *answer*?

Comment: This fits much better as a comment indeed.

Comment: It answered the question. You guys have way too much free time on your hands.

Comment: Seems to me like you do too, Ted, if you were compelled to spend time and give a non-answer ;-)

Comment: @TedShifrin For what it is worth, that was a sufficient answer to me as I suspected a typo.

Answer (score 3):

From what I recall, the actual statement of the inequality is
$$
\left|\langle x,y \rangle\right|\leq \lVert x\rVert\cdot\lVert y\rVert
$$
or, with your notations
$$
\left|x_1y_1 + x_2y_2\right|\leq \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}
$$
so the book is right (you'll have $|\lambda|$ on both sides). Note that this is a stronger statement than what you made, since we always have $x_1y_1 + x_2y_2\leq \left|x_1y_1 + x_2y_2\right|$.

Answer (score 0):

If you Chose to define $y_1 \geq x_1 $ and $  y_2 \geq x_2 $  without loss of generality then $ |\lambda | = \lambda $ since the choice is arbitrary in the formula you don't need to define $ \lambda > 0 $